# How to plot the marginal effect of a standard deviation increase and a standard deviation decrease both on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

I would like to plot the marginal effect of a standard deviation increase and a standard deviation decrease of a model on the same plot. I am using the `marginaleffects` package, but I am open to other solutions.

This is an example, suppose I have the following model:

```
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp * disp + factor(am), data = mtcars)
```

I would like to get the standard deviation increase  and standard deviation decrease of `hp`. The standard deviation is:

```
sd(mtcars$hp)
> sd(mtcars$hp)
[1] 68.56287
```

Then, I can plot individually each standard deviation using the codes:

```
plot1 <- plot_comparisons(mod, variables = list(hp = 68.56287), condition = "disp")
plot1
```

[image]

```
plot2 <- plot_comparisons(mod, variables = list(hp = -68.56287), condition = "disp")
plot2
```

[image]

Instead of having these values in two plots, I would like to get them in one plot. How can I do that?

EDIT: Following Vincent suggestion, I think I did it:

EDIT2: There was a mistake in previous code I posted, in which I had already standardized the data then I was calculating the plot with the standard deviation again (Thank you for pointing that out, Daniel). I corrected the codes.

```
plot1 <- plot_comparisons(mod, variables = list(hp = 68.56287), condition = "disp", draw = F)
plot1
plot2 <- plot_comparisons(mod, variables = list(hp = -68.56287), condition = "disp", draw = F)
plot2

plot1$example <- 1
plot2$example <- 2

plots <- rbind(plot1, plot2)

ggplot(plots, aes(disp, estimate, fill=factor(example), color = factor(example)))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=conf.low, ymax=conf.high, color=NULL), alpha=0.2)
```

[image]

Now I have to figure out how to fix the labels, then I am good.

Comment: I would make the same two calls with the `draw=FALSE` argument, combine the data frames, and plot them with `ggplot2`. This should be very easy.

Comment: Hi Vincent. Thank you for your answer. I am fairly new with R, can you show me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `draw=FALSE`, combine the datasets, and use `ggplot2`:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, hp <- scale(hp)[,1])
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp * disp + factor(am), data = mtcars2)
plot1 <- plot_comparisons(mod, variables = list(hp = 68.56287), condition = "disp", draw = FALSE)
plot2 <- plot_comparisons(mod, variables = list(hp = -68.56287), condition = "disp", draw = FALSE)
plot1$hp <- 69
plot2$hp <- -69
plots <- rbind(plot1, plot2)

ggplot(plots, aes(x = disp)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = factor(hp)), alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line(aes(y = estimate, color = factor(hp))) +
    labs(
        x = "Displacement",
        y = "Effect of a change in horsepower\non predicted miles per gallon",
        color = "Horsepower",
        fill = "Horsepower") +
    scale_color_manual(values = palette("Okabe-Ito")[2:3]) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = palette("Okabe-Ito")[2:3]) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Vincent! It was also very kind to show me how to make the plot look so good with the labels and all.

Comment: Shouldn't the values be 1 and -1, since the data is standardized?

Comment: You are right, Daniel! That was my mistake. Maybe that's the reason why marginal effect was giving the same values as predicted values. I am going to edit my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out, Daniel. It was my mistake to standardize the data and then calculate the plot with the standard deviation twice. I apologize to you and Vincent!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects), which let's you easily create plots of predictions or marginal effects at specific values:

```r
library(ggeffects)

mtcars2 <- within(mtcars, hp <- scale(hp)[,1])
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp * disp + factor(am), data = mtcars2)

# focal terms specified as strings
ggpredict(mod, c("disp", "hp[-68.5, 68.5]")) |> plot()
```

[image]

```r
# or as list
ggpredict(mod, list(disp = seq(100, 500, 10), hp = c(-68.5, 68.5))) |> plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! That's a really good suggestion.

Comment: Please be careful. I do NOT think that this gives you the same quantity that you were trying to plot above. `plot_comparisons()` gives you the change in outcome associated with a change in `hp` at different values of `disp`. `ggpredict()` gives you the predicted values (NOT the *change* in predicted values). In this case, it happens by coincidence that the numbers are in the same ballpark, but that feels misleading, as they are two conceptually distinct quantities. IIUC, `ggpredict()` is analogous to `plot_predictions()` in `marginaleffects`, and *not* to `plot_comparisons()`.

Comment: True, I just saw he used `plot_comparisons()`. But since the OP asked for plotting marginal effects for representative values at +/-1 SD, that's what ggpredict returns in this example. Victor, you may replace ggpredict with ggaverage, which gives you average marginal effects. If you're interested in the difference, see this section in the readme for details: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/#marginal-effects-marginalizing-over-non-focal-predictors

Comment: FWIW, I still disagree with your use of "marginal effects" as a synonym for "marginal means". On the face of it, the expression "effect" clearly implies that we are looking at a change in treatment/independent variable, not just a prediction (even if it is averaged). I also have not seen this equivalence anywhere, except on your website, and the Dickerman and Hernan (2020) reference you supply in support does not mention the terms. Obviously, I may have missed something, and I'd be very interested to read a source if you can point me to one.

Comment: Yeah, it remains a confusing concept/terminology, I guess. I have seen the usage in the context of "average predictions", but I think, usually, marginal effects refer to the difference between two predictions (like the dY/dX thing). That would mean that contrasts or pairwise comparisons could be seen as marginal effects, or at least as effects? The Dickeman/Hernan reference is related to "counterfactual predictions". But then, the question is whether "average marginal effects" is appropriate, too?

Comment: Just to make it clear, I want to plot the partial derivative of the interaction term. Which should give me the slope of hp conditioned by disp. So the Y axis should be displaying the effect of hp, not the predicted value of mpg.

Comment: @Daniel if you are thinking strictly about "average counterfactual predictions", then *no*, I do not think it would be appropriate to talk about "marginal effect". If you are looking at the contrast (difference) between predictions, I think there is a more reasonable case to be made.

Comment: @victor-shin i posted a full example with labels.